# Override subdirectory access for a certain user with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory, subdirectory

My Website is locked with htaccess in the apache2.conf, so you can only access it with user and password.

Now I want a subdirectory beeing only accessible for a certain user

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Access denied"
        AllowOverride All
        AuthBasicProvider file
        AuthUserFile /home/pi/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user

</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/MySite/MySubDirectory>
        AllowOverride none
        Require user alloweduser
</Directory>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: We cannot know what you are missing, since you don't tell us what your issue is.

Comment: This looks fine, what's not working?